# JavaScript localStorage not updating across multiple files

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm wanting to store an integer in localStorage and be able to use it over multiple JavaScript files. However, the other files are referencing an old value even after I've set it to a new one.

Here is a condensed version of the JSON file I'm working with:

```
export const data = [
    {
        "username": "steve"
    },
    {
        "username": "fred"
    }
```

Here is the code where I'm setting the value of the localStorage key:

```
import { renderMenu } from "./menuPage.js";
import { data } from "../data/data.js"; // JSON file containing data

const usernameInput = document.createElement("input");
const btn = document.createElement("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    var username = usernameInput.value;

    const user = data.find(u => (u.username === username));

    if (!user) {
        errText.textContent = "Incorrect username";
    } else {
        var dataIndex = data.indexOf(user);
        console.log(dataIndex);
    
        if (localStorage.getItem("dataIndexLocalStorage") !== dataIndex) {
            localStorage.setItem("dataIndexLocalStorage", JSON.stringify(dataIndex));
        }
        renderMenu();
    }
}
```

For example, if the username I entered was "steve", I expect `console.log(dataIndex);` to output `0`.

Here is the code where I'm getting the value of the localStorage key (this code is used on multiple JavaScript files):

```
import { data } from "../data/data.js";
const dataIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("dataIndexLocalStorage"));

export function renderMenu() {
    console.log(dataIndex);
}
```

Following the example stated before, I still expect `console.log(dataIndex);` to output `0`. It does this in some cases (sometimes it just outputs `null`).

In the cases where it does indeed output `0`, if I was to enter "fred" as the username, I expect `console.log(dataIndex);` to output `1`. However, in the renderMenu() function, `console.log(dataIndex);` still outputs `0`, not `1` as it does so in the main code.

Am I missing something really basic? It seems strange that it doesn't update the value everywhere.

I appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: Your code creates a new `<input>` and immediately checks its value. The value will be the empty string ("").

Comment: You are using modules your `dataIndex = parseInt(...)` statement is only going to be executed once (the first time the module is imported), not each time renderMenu is called.

Comment: @Pointy My apologies, everything beneath the <input> only gets called when a button is pressed.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Is there a way to guarantee that it will be imported every time renderMenu is called?

Comment: I just had to put `dataIndex = parseInt(...)` into the renderMenu function, and declare `var dataIndex` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this question now just incase other people come across it:

I just had to put dataIndex = parseInt(...) into the renderMenu function, and declare var dataIndex as a global variable at the top of the file:

```
import { data } from "../data/data.js";
var dataIndex;

export function renderMenu() {
    dataIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("dataIndexLocalStorage"));
    console.log(dataIndex);
}
```